# ¿como puedo trabajar conel plugin bootstrapvalidator-0.5.2 para validar form?

Tags: html, jquery

estoy aqui porque tengo problemas usando el plugins bootstrapvalidator-0.5.2, cuando se esta validando la informacion quisiera que los mesajes de validacion se mostraran abajo de cada input.

estoy usando Jquery y boostrap 3

porque este es el resultado que obtengo.
[image: entra inpu nombre]

**este en mi formulario:**

```
<form class="form registerForm" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="box-body">
            <!--nombre-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="newLotePiku">NOMBRE:</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control puntero-i" name="newname" id="newName" placeholder="INGRESE NOMBRE.">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--fecha-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="text">FECHA:</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9 date datepicker">
                    <input type="text" min="2018/01/01" max="2999/12/31" class="form-control" name="newFecha" id="newfecha" placeholder="INGRESE FECHA" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon manito-clic">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

**este es mi codigo javascrip(plugins bootstrapvalidator-0.5.2):**
donde estoy haciendo la validación del formulario.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.registerForm').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'Este valor no es valido',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                newname: {
                    message: 'El nombre de usuario no es válido.',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'El nombre de usuario es obligatorio y no puede estar vacío.'


                 },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'El nombre de usuario debe tener más de 6 y menos de 30 caracteres.'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                        message: 'El nombre de usuario solo puede consistir en alfabético, número y guión bajo'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion que me resulto a mi fue esta:

como pueden ver si quita algunas class y se agregan otras.
me sirvio para usar correctamente boostrapvalidator, datepicker sin tener problemas de diseño responsive.

```
<

!--fecha-->
    <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
        <label class="control-label" for="text">FECHA:</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg date datepicker">
            <input type="text" min="2018/01/01" max="2999/12/31" class="form-control" name="newFecha" id="newfecha" placeholder="INGRESE FECHA" required>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```